# Dispatch Source timer schedule timout

Tags: swift, asynchronous, timer, dispatch

With the following Swift code, I'm trying to create a task that runs every hour:

```
let queue: DispatchQueue = .main
let timer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(queue: queue)
timer.schedule(deadline: .now(), repeating: .seconds(3600), leeway: .milliseconds(100)
timer.setEventHandler { [weak self] in
    // run code
}
```

Now, when I have the repeating set at a lower number, say 10 or event 150 seconds, it triggers as expected both in the foreground and background (or, rather, once the foreground hits it triggers, if the timer went off while in the background).
However, when I let the app timeout to the lock screen, and wait for an hour, it doesn't display.

Is there some timeout that Apple has for DispatchSource schedules? If so, what is it? And is there any way to change or get around it?

**Edit**

I don't want special functionality when it backgrounds, I want the code to keep running as normal and to trigger the event handler when the timeout happens, even if it's in the background

Comment: Why do you need the timer to run in the background? Just write down the time when you go into the background, look at the clock when you go into the foreground, and do the right thing based on that.

Comment: I don't need special functionality dependent on background/foreground, I want it to run irrelevant of background/foreground

Comment: But why? All a timer does is fire at an interval. I’m saying you can arrange that in spite of having gone into the background

Answer (score 0):

I ended up taking matt's suggestion and saving the time every time the code gets called, as seen below. Worked well!

```
let timeOfLastCheck = Date()
let queue: DispatchQueue = .main
let timer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(queue: queue)
timer.schedule(deadline: .now(), repeating: .seconds(3600), leeway: .milliseconds(100)
timer.setEventHandler { [weak self] in
    timeOfLastCheck = Date()
    // run code
}
```

And elsewhere, where the timer is actually getting created:

```
    let notificationCenter: NotificationCenter = .default
    let activeNotificationToken = notificationCenter.addObserver(
        forName: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification,
        object: nil,
        queue: nil
    ) { [weak self] _ in
        let now = Date()
        if let `self` = self,
           let timeInterval = TimeInterval(dispatchTimeInterval: self.interval), // TimeInterval is extended elsewhere to be able to take in a DispatchTimeInterval in the init
           now > timeOfLastCheck.addingTimeInterval(timeInterval) {
            self.timeOfLastCheck = Date()
            // run code
        }
    }
```